# oracle data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, olap

****UPDATE***

i will try to explain the situation again:
i have one datamart which contains all the clients and the original payments along with status and fiscal period in yyyymmdd format. the status needs to be matched with the status in another table so that i get only those client names and fiscal periods where status_datamart=status_table and status_table in ('inactive', 'active'). this data is now inserted into a table called 'inv' which contains: 
PORTFOLIO_INV, CLIENT_INV,ACCT_TYPE_INV,PERIOD,DESK,STATUS,PRIOR_OCA_CALC,PRINCIPAL,CUR_BAL

the second datamart again contains client, fiscal_period, payments(gross and net), transaction_type.
one query is used to fetch only those records from this datamart where the txn type is matched with another table and txn category is 'gross'.
second query has same filters as above, only txn category is now changed to 'net'.

The reason for 2 queries to get gross and net is that the data is in following format:

client1 | fiscal period| status | gross
client2 | fiscal period| status | gross
client1 | fiscal period| status | net
client3 | fiscal period| status | gross

so i use query one to store gross into one table 'pmt' :
PORTFOLIO_PMT,CLIENT_PMT,ACCT_TYPE_PMT,PERIOD_PMT,DETAIL_TRANSACTION_TYPE,DETAIL_DESK_AT_PMT,DETAIL_STATUS_AT_PMT,PRIOR_OCA_CALC_PMT,DETAIL_AMOUNT_PMT

and second query to store into another table 'net':
PORTFOLIO_NET,CLIENT_NET,ACCT_TYPE_NET,PERIOD_NET,DETAIL_TRANSACTION_TYPE_NET,DETAIL_DESK_AT_PMT_NET,DETAIL_STATUS_AT_NET,PRIOR_OCA_CALC_NET,DETAIL_AMOUNT_NET

constraints:
client_inv=client_pmt=client_net
period= period_pmt=period=net

hope it helps...

---

i am writing a query that will retrieve the name of client, fiscal year and principal amount from table T1, sum(current payments) from another table T2 (for same client and same fiscal period) and the sum(net) from third table(for same client as in T1 and T2) . the query took 2132.78 seconds to complete for around 3400 records in T1, 939 in T2 and 103 in T3.

is there a way in which i can NOT use joins and just fetch the data I want quickly?
The total number of records will vary in each table depending what was the principal amount and how many payments have been received.

Comment: @joiner - Post the query plan in addition to the query.  When you talk about "3400 records in T1", are you stating that there are 3400 total rows in T1?  Or that you are retrieving only 3400 rows from T1?  If you mean that you are only retrieving 3400 rows, how many rows are in T1 that you are not retrieving (and the same for T2 and T3)?

Comment: at this point, there are 3400 rows in t1. and joining all these records based on client name and period

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried analyzing why your query is slow?

Looks like you dont have to use joins, but rather a union of all three queries. It looks like independant functionality.

You need to use joins when you have a table called contact and another table called contact_address where there is related information to the main table.

If your information is not related, then you could get the results through an union where the structure of your results is the same.

Comment: i used UNION but the result was only client name, period and sum(principal), it omitted sum(payments) and sum(net)

Comment: select client0, period0, sum(principal) from temp_inv group by client0, period0 union select client_pmt, period1, sum(detail_amount_pmt) from temp_pmt group by client_pmt, period1 union select client_net, period2, sum(detail_amount_net) from temp_pmt_net group by client_net, period2

Answer (score 0):

2132 seconds for the data volumes you suggest seem to indicate that the join criteria might not be accurate and you might be seeing a MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN in your execution plan.
If you were to trace your request and post the tkprof output or just explain the SQL and post the plan, it'll be beneficial in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: select client0, period0, sum(principal) from temp_inv group by client0, period0
union
select client_pmt, period1, sum(detail_amount_pmt) from temp_pmt group by client_pmt, period1
union
select client_net, period2, sum(detail_amount_net) from temp_pmt_net group by client_net, period2